# 22.04.3 LTS: Why is power draw showing "ERR!" in nvidia-smi?

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, cuda

Why is the power draw (Pwr:Usage/Cap) for my NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti showing "ERR!" in nvidia-smi?

This is my pc specs

```
venv) luffy@predator:~/fern/forge-code/backend/gpt-service/gpt-2-Pytorch$ inxi -Fxz
System:
  Kernel: 6.5.0-25-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: Unity
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Acer product: Predator PH315-51 v: V1.26
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: CFL model: Sienta_CFS v: V1.26 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: Insyde v: 1.26 date: 03/27/2019
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 32.8 Wh (100.0%) condition: 32.8/48.9 Wh (67.0%)
    volts: 16.6 min: 15.2 model: LG PABAS0241231 status: Full
CPU:
  Info: 6-core model: Intel Core i7-8750H bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    arch: Coffee Lake rev: A cache: L1: 384 KiB L2: 1.5 MiB L3: 9 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 875 high: 900 min/max: 800/4100 cores: 1: 900 2: 900
    3: 800 4: 900 5: 900 6: 900 7: 900 8: 900 9: 800 10: 900 11: 800 12: 900
    bogomips: 52799
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
    vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: i915 v: kernel bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
    vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: nvidia v: 550.54.14 bus-ID: 01:00.0
  Device-3: Quanta HD Webcam type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 1-5:4
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa gpu: i915
    resolution: 1: 1920x1080~144Hz 2: 1920x1080~144Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP107GL High Definition Audio
    vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
    bus-ID: 01:00.1
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.5.0-25-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi driver: iwlwifi v: kernel
    bus-ID: 00:14.3
  IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 3000
    bus-ID: 06:00.1
  IF: enp6s0f1 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-1: br-5079ae37e513 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-2: br-d3fd53b81a04 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-3: cali0a7bef59a06 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-4: cali9c7d7561424 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-5: docker0 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-6: vethaf5ce75 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-7: vxlan.calico state: unknown speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP) type: USB
    driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 1-14:5
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 2 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 3.0 lmp-v: 5.1
RAID:
  Hardware-1: Intel 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] driver: ahci
    v: 3.0 bus-ID: 00:17.0
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.03 TiB used: 101.07 GiB (9.6%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: SK Hynix model: HFS128G39TND-N210A
    size: 119.24 GiB
  ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: HGST (Hitachi) model: HTS721010A9E630
    size: 931.51 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 116.32 GiB used: 101.02 GiB (86.8%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 52.4 MiB (10.3%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/sda1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 512 KiB (0.0%) file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 84.0 C pch: 80.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 445 Uptime: 48m Memory: 15.45 GiB used: 7.33 GiB (47.4%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.4.0 Packages: 3325 Shell: Bash
  v: 5.1.16 inxi: 3.3.13
```

And this is my nvidia-smi output

```
(venv) luffy@predator:~/fern/forge-code/backend/gpt-service/gpt-2-Pytorch$ nvidia-smi
Sun Mar 17 13:43:43 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.54.14              Driver Version: 550.54.14      CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti     Off |   00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   83C    P8             N/A / ERR!  |      47MiB /   4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      5874      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             45MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I do not understand why ERR is showing in my output .